# How to remove vertical space after numbered item?

Tags: lists, mcexam

I am using the `mcexam` package. How to remove the yellow space shown in the picture?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[output=exam]{mcexam}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{mcquestions}
    \question Test question I
        \begin{mcanswerslist}
            \answer answer a
            \answer[correct] answer b
            \answer answer c
            \answer answer d
        \end{mcanswerslist}
     \question Test question II
        \begin{mcanswerslist}
            \answer answer a
            \answer answer b
            \answer answer c
            \answer[correct] answer d
        \end{mcanswerslist}
        \question Test question III
        \begin{mcanswerslist}
            \answer answer a
            \answer answer b
            \answer answer c
            \answer[correct] answer d
        \end{mcanswerslist}
    \question Test question IV
        \begin{mcanswerslist}
            \answer answer a
            \answer answer b
            \answer answer c
            \answer[correct] answer d
\end{mcanswerslist}
\end{mcquestions}

\end{document}
```

[image: This picture]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lists of `mcexam` are defined using [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), and the spacing can be adjusted using its command `setlist`. From the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/mcexam) of `mcexam`, I think the list of which you want to reduce the spacing is called `setmcquestions`, and its default settings (as given on page 14 of the documentation) are

```
\setlist[setmcquestions]{label=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*}.,
    ref=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*},
    itemsep=2\baselineskip,
    topsep=2\baselineskip}
```

The spacing that you find too large is the spacing between different items, which is given by the value of `itemsep`. Setting a lower value will reduce the spacing.

In the following example, I reduced the spacing to `.5\baselineskip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Packages

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm, portrait]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[output=exam]{mcexam}

\setlist[setmcquestions]{
    label=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*}.,
    ref=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*},
    itemsep=.5\baselineskip,
    topsep=2\baselineskip}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{mcquestions}
    \question Test question I
        \begin{mcanswerslist}
            \answer answer a
            \answer[correct] answer b
            \answer answer c
            \answer answer d
        \end{mcanswerslist}
     \question Test question II
        \begin{mcanswerslist}
            \answer answer a
            \answer answer b
            \answer answer c
            \answer[correct] answer d
        \end{mcanswerslist}
        \question Test question III
        \begin{mcanswerslist}
            \answer answer a
            \answer answer b
            \answer answer c
            \answer[correct] answer d
        \end{mcanswerslist}
    \question Test question IV
        \begin{mcanswerslist}
            \answer answer a
            \answer answer b
            \answer answer c
            \answer[correct] answer d
\end{mcanswerslist}
\end{mcquestions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much